# Change global scope for callback in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is kind of tricky. I'd like to change global scope within passed callback

```
var Class = function() {
};

Class.prototype.add = function(a, b) {
    return a + " + " + b;
};

Class.prototype.api = function(callback) {
    callback.apply(this);
};

var ClosedStuff = new Class();

ClosedStuff.api(function() {
    console.log(this.add(2, 2));
});
```

This stuff works, but is there a way to omit `this.` without eval? Like

```
ClosedStuff.api(function() {
    console.log(add(2, 2));
});
```

I don't want to pollute global namespace, and would love to not have to use any namespace prefixes. ES6 and node specific solutions welcome

Comment: Not getting that at all. How would anyone know what instance to invoke a method against if you don't tell it? I assume you're not referring to something as simple as just `var add = this.add.bind(this);`? I guess you're looking for some kind of replacement default scope or magic implied prefixing of `this` inside an object method, which no, does not exist.

Comment: Given the toy examples you could use a fluent API to get rid of a lot of the repetition. But it shouldn't be the primary thought when considering this API design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This stuff works, but is there a way to omit `this`. without `eval`?

Not without replacing it with something else, such as passing the instance as an argument to the callback:

```
Class.prototype.api = function(callback) {
    callback(this);
};
// ...
ClosedStuff.api(function(inst) {
    console.log(inst.add(2, 2));
});
```

...which is basically what you're doing with `Function#call` and `this`.

Comment: I know I expect a little too much from ES6 features, but is there some kind of voodoo where I could use reflect or something like that? Maybe some Proxy on global object?

Comment: @Misiur: I can't see anything that would apply here, no.

Comment: Such is life. Thanks for help anyway!

Comment: But I don't really get this. You're simply passing the `this` pointer as a parameter to the callback, instead of as its `this`. It works, of course, but wherein lies the advantage in doing this, and how does it answer the OP's question, besides allowing him to not say `this` and say `inst` instead? The OP seems to be asking something else, but I'm not sure what (although I took a guess in my answer).

Comment: @torazaburo: I didn't say it was better. In fact, I rather thought I implied the opposite. It's an *alternative*, not a better one.